# Settings to change the theme?

Tags: ros, answers.ros.org

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

Since questions about this site should also be posed here: 
Is there an option to set the theme of answers.ros.org? 
The new theme doesn't suit me and I couldn't find anything in my profile.

Greetings 
Felix

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/27486/settings-to-change-the-theme?/) by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) on ROS Answers with karma: 6468 on 2012-02-13

Post score: 8

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) on 2012-02-13**:
Agreed. I find the heading font difficult to read which makes it hard to scan through the list of questions.

**Comment by [Asomerville](https://answers.ros.org/users/351/asomerville/) on 2012-02-13**:
It's nice to see they updated the style, but I'm having a really hard time reading that font, and readjusting to the new spacing and such. Hopefully they'll take feedback into consideration and at the very least allow us to change it in our settings though I'm not sure if Askbot has that possiblity.

**Comment by [seanarm](https://answers.ros.org/users/443/seanarm/) on 2012-02-13**:
Thanks for posting this question. I didn't want to be "that guy". This theme is extremely difficult on the eyes. Search is broken-- it returns multiples of almost all of the search results. Also, in Firefox, going to your profile, then clicking on a link to one of your answers, causes a strange redirect to http://answers.ros.orgundefined19130/ where the number was something to do with the answer/question number.

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2012-02-13**:
Thank you for the question.

**Comment by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) on 2012-02-13**:
Regarding the multiple results in search, see this ticket: https://code.ros.org/trac/ros/ticket/3844

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We will be updating the skin back to ROS style shortly.  If you find any errors please ticket them [here](https://code.ros.org/trac/ros/newticket?component=answers.ros.org)

View open tickets [here](https://code.ros.org/trac/ros/query?status=assigned&status=new&status=reopened&group=milestone&component=answers.ros.org&order=priority&col=id&col=summary&col=component&col=status&col=type&col=priority&col=milestone)

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2012-02-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2